# Ubuntu Eclipse : Backspace key started working like Delete key

Tags: keyboard, eclipse, editor, keys

Yes,

Its happens suddenly when i am working on eclipse don't know how. I am working on eclipse, backspace key works all fine but suddenly its started working like delete key (When press backspace we expect to delete backward characters but its deleting front characters).

Is their its an eclipse functionality? or bug i am not sure. if Functionality then let know how to make it correct.

Its really weird type of issue. Cant able to work smoothly.

Thanks.

GOT SOLVED VIEW : [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824076/ubuntu-eclipse-backspace-key-started-working-like-delete-key)

Comment: I have the exact same problem since yesterday evening. I don't know what I did to deserve such an awful pain, that's really annoying! I posted a question on StackOverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823185/backspace-key-is-reverted-in-eclipse-mars

Comment: By the way, I have the problem on a windows 7 machine, so I suppose it's not Ubuntu-related.

Comment: I think this happens because of some multiple key pressed that we don't know. Not sure. Hope some eclipse guys help to sort it out this issue its really annoying.

Comment: GOT SOLVED VIEW HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824076/ubuntu-eclipse-backspace-key-started-working-like-delete-key

Answer (score 3):

same problem here.
I solved it by windows>preferences and there General>Appearance>Keys.
I typed "delete" as filter and notice - it's exists 2 entries for "Delete".
The first one was linked to "backspace", the other one was linked to "del".
i has unbind the first one - voila - all okay now.
Hope it's help for you, Tor Alfmi